# how can import correctly two variables from another Python file in the same folder?

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I would like to read the values of 2 variables existent in another python file *'save_state_mod.py'*

I cannot understand what's wrong with my code here:

```
 from save_state_mod import event , save_missing_weight

 smw = save_state_mod.save_missing_weight
 ev = save_state_mod.event
```

I get every time this error : Undefined variable 'save_state_mod'
or NameError: name 'save_state_mod' is not defined

the file save_state_mod.py is in the same folder, i even added a `__init__.py` file in the same folder

please help me because i am stuck

Comment: You imported `save_missing_weight`, so you can refer to it directly.  You don't need to put `save_state_mod.` in front of it.

Answer (score 3):

You have imported the names `event` and `save_missing_weight`, you didn't import `save_state_mod`, so you can just use:

```
from save_state_mod import event, save_missing_weight

# use the names directly
smw = save_missing_weight
ev = event
```

Or, if you want `save_missing_weight`, you can do:

```
import save_state_mod

smw = save_state_mod.save_missing_weight
ev = save_state_mod.event
```

Comment: yes but i still get this whatever i do : 'File "C:\list_events.py", line 3, in <module>
    from save_state_mod import event, save_missing_weight'

Comment: @MBENKI You still get what? An error? If yes, in what line do you get an error?

Comment: i get an error on line 3 "Traceback (most recent call last) : File "C:\list_events.py", line 3, in <module>
    from save_state_mod import event, save_missing_weight"

Comment: @MBENKI Are you sure you have the file `save_state_mod.py` in the same folder as the one that is importing it?

Comment: Absolutely ! i have *list_events.py* and *save_state_mod.py* inside the same folder, and i already verified if i mispelled something but everything's seem correct ...

Comment: @MBENKI Do you have a `import save_state_mod` in the file `list_events.py`?

Comment: Yes of course i did just like in the answer you gave at first

Comment: @MBENKI I'm sorry I didn't ask the right question, I meant to ask do you have a `import list_events` (or `from list_events import ...` or any import statement that uses `list_events`) in the `save_state_mod.py` file?

Comment: no because i have to import variables from *save_stae_mod.py* to *list_events.py*

Comment: @MBENKI In this case can you post the entire error text, not just the first line.

Comment: I already did, i doesn't say error but only that Traceback notification, anyway i am trying to avoid that import and working something out thank you so much for your time and attention, but i 'll post here as soon as figure this out count on me :D thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
from save_state_mod import *
```

or this

```
import save_state_mod.event
import save_state_mod.save_missing_weight
```